# Job interview, but is it a real place?

Tags: interviewing

I applied for a job and got a reply from their HR that they want to schedule a phone interview.  As a result, I was trying to find more info on the company and quickly realized that there is no Website or any way of verifying anything regarding this company.

When you Google the company, the only search results are job openings at various job boards.  On LinkedIn, many postings, but no company profile.  I tried also googling the email address and the phone number provided, but this also had NO results.  The email also does not reference anything regarding the specific position in which I applied for, which also makes me concerned.  Below is a copy of the email.  I don't think it's a scam, but am worried if this may be some "BS" job.

> Dear Glen!
>
> We are sending a reply in regards to the resume/interest you submitted
>   for Company XYZ.
>
> After reviewing your information, we are very interested in scheduling
>   a 10 - 15 minute phone interview with our hiring manager at our office
>   location in Columbus! During this interview, the hiring manager will
>   review your experience/qualifications and provide more details
>   regarding the position (duties/clients), as well as upcoming growth
>   opportunities. Since we are looking to fill the position quickly, we
>   typically do interviews on the upcoming business day between 11:00AM -
>   12:30PM., please call me to secure a time.
>
> You may call me directly at (614) XXX-XXXX to secure an interview time
>   with the director. Our HR Team will confirm your interview time and
>   send a detailed email outlining everything you will need to be
>   prepared!

Comment: Looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: Probably bogus, but if they did exist, you just breached their confidence by putting their email *with their company name* on a public forum.

Comment: The company technically does exist in Ohio as a corporation and was incorporated 11/21/16. The incorporator was apparently a senior in college in 2015. That's all that comes up on a cursory search. You can find the info yourself by going to the corporation search and entering the company's name. It lists a physical address.

Comment: Something that does strike me a bit odd. The interview times are between 11 and 12:30. That's during lunch and **only** during lunch. Were I to hazard a guess, I think you have someone trying to do this part-time. I would also not be shocked if it turns into some kind of MLM thing. I've seen it before. Regardless, make a phone call. It can't really hurt and I'm very curious. :)

Comment: This response has all the hallmarks of an MLM intro.  I would bet its a Essential Oils thing.

Comment: This is a standard multi-level marketing pitch.  Keep away.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings nice catch. I should have seen that with the company name.

Answer (score 5):

If you got an email reply, you have a domain to look up, from a casual browser visit to a WHOIS lookup. If HR's email was sent from a mail provider like GMail, that's a bit of a red flag indeed. I should also mention looking at their email signature for completeness sake.

I would also recommend querying the your locale's business registry office. The [UK Government Website](https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-a-company) has a section on how to do just that, for example.

Regardless, this is a very good question to reply back to HR with.

> This is slightly embarrassing but I've been unable to find your website! I'd like to be more prepared for my upcoming interview, could you please send me a link?

But yeah, it does sound sketchy.

Comment: I used this exact approach when I got a job interview request from a great company in NYC that was a little too good to be true. Turns out, the website was registered to some PO box in Atlanta. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯